# Android Studio loses files after git branch change

Tags: git, flutter, android-studio

As the title says, Android studio loses/removes project directories on branch change. This happens for the same branch every time. It's a flutter project, repository is hosted on github. I tried creating a new branch from this one and the same thing happens. When checking out other branches, the project directories are all there. [Android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrwWz.png)

## Update:

flutter doctor:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.1, on macOS 11.6 20G165 darwin-x64, locale en-HR)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.56.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.55.2)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)
```

.gitignore:

```
# Created by https://www.gitignore.io/api/dart,flutter,visualstudiocode
# Edit at https://www.gitignore.io/?templates=dart,flutter,visualstudiocode

### Dart ###
# See https://www.dartlang.org/guides/libraries/private-files

# Files and directories created by pub
.dart_tool/
.packages
build/
# If you're building an application, you may want to check-in your pubspec.lock
pubspec.lock

# Directory created by dartdoc
# If you don't generate documentation locally you can remove this line.
doc/api/

# Avoid committing generated Javascript files:
*.dart.js
*.info.json      # Produced by the --dump-info flag.
*.js             # When generated by dart2js. Don't specify *.js if your
                 # project includes source files written in JavaScript.
*.js_
*.js.deps
*.js.map

### Flutter ###
# Flutter/Dart/Pub related
**/doc/api/
.flutter-plugins
.flutter-plugins-dependencies
.pub-cache/
.pub/

# IntelliJ related
*.iml
*.ipr
*.iws
.idea/

# Android related
**/android/**/gradle-wrapper.jar
**/android/.gradle
**/android/captures/
**/android/gradlew
**/android/gradlew.bat
**/android/local.properties
**/android/**/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java
**/android/key.properties

# iOS/XCode related
**/ios/**/*.mode1v3
**/ios/**/*.mode2v3
**/ios/**/*.moved-aside
**/ios/**/*.pbxuser
**/ios/**/*.perspectivev3
**/ios/**/*sync/
**/ios/**/.sconsign.dblite
**/ios/**/.tags*
**/ios/**/.vagrant/
**/ios/**/DerivedData/
**/ios/**/Icon?
**/ios/**/Pods/
**/ios/**/.symlinks/
**/ios/**/profile
**/ios/**/xcuserdata
**/ios/.generated/
**/ios/Flutter/App.framework
**/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework
**/ios/Flutter/Generated.xcconfig
**/ios/Flutter/app.flx
**/ios/Flutter/app.zip
**/ios/Flutter/flutter_assets/
**/ios/ServiceDefinitions.json
**/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.*
**ios/Flutter/flutter_export_environment.sh
**ios/Flutter/.last_build_id
**ios/Flutter/Flutter.podspec

# Exceptions to above rules.
!**/ios/**/default.mode1v3
!**/ios/**/default.mode2v3
!**/ios/**/default.pbxuser
!**/ios/**/default.perspectivev3
!/packages/flutter_tools/test/data/dart_dependencies_test/**/.packages

### VisualStudioCode ###
.vscode/*
!.vscode/tasks.json
!.vscode/extensions.json

# Miscellaneous
*.class
*.log
*.pyc
*.swp
.DS_Store
.atom/
.buildlog/
.svn/

### VisualStudioCode Patch ###
# Ignore all local history of files
.history

# End of https://www.gitignore.io/api/dart,flutter,visualstudiocode
*.env
```

Comment: Did the other branch contain those files? Has that branch removed those files?

Comment: What version of Android Studio are you using? What is in the .gitignore file?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this by adding all files from `.idea/` to git except for `workspace.xml`. I suppose this was happening because `vcs.xml`, `*.iml` and other files from `.idea/` weren't in the repository and were not generated when changing the branch but only after resetting Android studio.